# Take the voltage out of a voltage divider with no distortion

Tags: impedance, voltage-divider

In the (simplified) schematics below, I would like to measure the voltage at point A with an instrument that I have to plug at point B.

[image: Schematics]

The problem is that if I simply add a wire between A and B, the voltage divider will change (from V/1000 -> V/100000). Is there a way to do that ? (a component, ...)

On the schematic, I drew everything I can't change (no control on), but else I am "free" to do whatever it needs.

**EDIT** Answers to a few questions :

- I don't "manually plug" something to B. There is some sort of analog to digital converter circuit that is always there and a microcontroller that talks with it
- V is 220V alternative (electricity "directly from the wall")
- the real schematic is VERY BIG, and this is a simplified case that I also have been struggling with in other projects

Comment: Can you use active components like transistors or IC's?

Comment: yes, anything I want

Comment: @Thomas   What's the max voltage, which you'll be applying across the 10Ω ?

Comment: Use an op-amp in a follower configuration.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you have to "plug" the instrument at point B?

Comment: You could use a sample and hold technique - switch a grounded capacitor to A and let it charge up then on switching back to B take an instant reading - even a reading that is a bit late (cap discharging) can be retrospectively calculated knowing the exponential decay stuff.

Comment: Why have you posted a simplified schematic? What else is there that you are not showing? And what is the range of V?

Comment: What do you mean by no control on?

Comment: @PhilFrost I have edited my question

Comment: @scld I can't change the voltage divider nor the 10 ohm resistor nor the point B and the thing that measures it

Comment: @NickAlexeev I have edited my question : 220V alternative

Comment: Should the voltage reaching point B be AC or it can be a rectified voltage too? Is the voltage level reaching point B important or it doesn't matter as long as it can be measured? What are the available DC supply voltages in your device?

Comment: @alexan_e voltage in B must be equal to voltage in A. It is important to know it. (The resistance of 1k is unknown but between 0 and 1k). There is a 5v DC supply too

Comment: The accepted answer is not going to solve your problem. Point A can be anywhere from 0v to 2.2v AC, that voltage need to be applied to B without changing and also be measured accurately. In addition you don't have any symmetric voltage available that could help power the buffer.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by "point B can be anywhere from 0 to 2.2". The OpAmp in this configuration doesn't force Vout=Vin ?

Comment: You said in the comments that the lower resistance of the divider is unknown and can be 0 to 1k so A can be 0 to 2.2v. Using an opamp to amplify an AC voltage having a single rail supply will be a problem I think. Maybe if you apply an offset you can solve the problem although the max swing of 2.2v AC (peak to peak) is more than 5v.

Comment: @alexan_e voltage will be from -0.2 to 0.2V, does it change something or not ? is your concern about the 5V range of the opamp or something else ?

Comment: Something went wrong in my calculation, you are right it's just 0 to 0.22v. You'll still need to add an offset to the input to handle the negative voltage and use a decoupling capacitor to get rid of it at the output.

Comment: A nitpick, perhaps, but the 10\$\Omega\$ resistor does not inherently cause any distortion, it just reduces the signal by about 100:1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is usually addressed with a [buffer amplifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_amplifier).  The goal of the buffer amplifier circuit is to have a high impedance input and low impedance output.

A very common way of doing this is to wire an OpAmp in a voltage follower configuration.

[image] ([source](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/opampvar2.html) of the picture)

Simply put, if you connect the voltage divider to *V<sub>in</sub>* and connect the 10Ω between *V<sub>out</sub>* and ground, then the voltage divider will not "see" the additional 10Ω in parallel with 1kΩ.

**edit**
The potential problem with 10Ω (low impedance load) is that it will draw current (*I=V<sub>out</sub>/R<sub>load</sub>*) from the OpAmp output, and the OpAmp has to be able be able to supply it.

- Let's assume a scenario in which the voltage after the divider is 0.5V.  Then the OpAmp will need to supply 50mA of output current.  This falls into the the specs of a typical vanilla OpAmp.
- Assume another scenario in which the voltage after the divider is 6V.  Then the OpAmp will need to supply 600mA of output current.  This is outside the spec of a typical OpAmp (although this still can be achiehved with an additional high current stage).

BTW.  I'll hazard a guess that you'll have 0.312V max after your 1:1001 voltage divider, if you apply 220 VAC to the voltage divider.  220 VAC is an RMS value.

Comment: A 10 Ohm resistor will not be an easy load for a generic opamp, at least not if the voltage level is higher than a couple of volts.

Comment: @alexan_e  I agree.  Nevertheless, this is a reasonable place for the O.P. to start.

Comment: So will this be ok ? The input voltage is 0.2V max

Comment: @alexan_e What you say looks interesting. Can you say a bit more about the 10 ohm problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is fun: -

[image]

The capacitor is initially conected to point A and allowed to charge then the moment the cap switches to position B, a reading should be taken. It helps if the cap is fairly large in value so that by the time you've taken a measurement at B, it won't have discharged very much. I'm thinking fast ADC here and a 10uF capacitor.

CR charge time will be much slower than discharge time so maybe you can also oscillate between A and B and compare slopes of charge and discharge to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for this smart solution but (I have edited my question) I don't want to make just one measurement by hand

Comment: @Thomas My answer works better when automated - an analogue switch can "move" the capacitor from point A to point B and the instant it moves, an ADC can perform a conversion. Given that analogue switches have non-zero ohm resistance there will, in effect be a potential divider with the 10 ohms but, that can be accounted for by a calibration cycle that injects a known voltage onto the capacitor (when it is connected to point A).

Comment: In fact, the calibration cycle can happen with the voltage injected at point B - as soon as you remove the forced calibration voltage (that has charged the capacitor), the voltage will instantly droop then decay. The droop tells you the the on-resistance of the analogue switch. Using this method there need only be one point B and multiple point A nodes if that helps.

Comment: @Andyaka Really I like the way you are simplify our life !!!!